# Map function in Reactjs is putting addition objects in the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to have a set of input fields right after one another like a terminal.

The `Page` component looks like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NewLine from "./newLine";

export class Page extends Component {
    state = {
        numberOfLine: 0,
        lines: [{ value: "", id: 0, displayInputs: true}]
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="terminal">
                    <p className="prompt">
                        Hey there! This is a pre rendered line.
                    </p>
                    {this.state.lines.map(l => (
                        <NewLine
                            key={this.state.numberOfLine}
                            handelWhatever={this.handelWhatever}
                            line={l}
                        ></NewLine>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }



    handelWhatever = (string_value, Tid) => {
        // console.log(string_value, Tid);
        // console.log(this.state.lines.filter(l => l.id != Tid));
        const num = this.state.numberOfLine + 1;
        this.setState({
            numberOfLine: this.state.lines.length + 1,
            lines: [
                ...this.state.lines.filter(line => line.id !== Tid),
                { value: string_value, id: Tid, displayInput: false },
                { value: "", id: num, displayInput: true }
            ]
        });
    };


export default Page;
```

and my `NewLine` component looks like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class NewLine extends Component {
    state = {
        id: this.props.line.id,
        value: this.props.line.value,
        displayInput: this.props.line.displayInput
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <p className=output>
                    {this.state.displayInput && (
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="here"
                            value={this.state.value}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            onKeyDown={this.handelEnter}
                        />
                    )}
                    {this.state.value}
                </p>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    };

    handelEnter = event => {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
            this.props.handelWhatever(event.target.value, this.state.id);
    }
    };

}

export default NewLine;
```

When I enter the "something" in the input it should make a `NewLine` component and delete the input from the previous one so that user can type on the newly rendered line that is why I have bool in the New Line state.

The states updates perfectly but when i user input it takes all the previous ones and render them, i.e,
Initial Stage

```
> Hey there! This is a pre rendered line.
>
```

User Input : 'ls'

```
> Hey there! This is a pre rendered line.
> ls
>
```

User Input : 'cd'

```
> Hey there! This is a pre rendered line.
> ls
> ls
> cd
```

and so on

I don't know what is going on I tried printing the state of the Parent component and it has desired number of lines  In the map if I do console.log just after one input I will get

```
{value: "ls", id: 1, displayInput: false}
{value: "ls", id: 1, displayInput: false}
{value: "", id: 2, displayInput: true}
```

console logging in map is like this

```
{this.state.lines.map(l => {
    console.log(l);
    return (
        <NewLine
        key={this.state.numberOfLine}
        handelWhatever={this.handelWhatever}
        line={l}
        ></NewLine>
      );
})}
```

Comment: Why not update the state once in the `handelWhatever` function?

Comment: `LId !== lId` fix the case of your variables. So `handelWhatever = (string_value, LId) => {` should become `handelWhatever = (string_value, lId) => {`

Comment: @EmileBergeron `  this.setState({
   lines: [
    ...this.state.lines.filter(line => line.id !== Tid),
    { value: string_value, id: Tid, displayInput: false },
    { value: "", id: num, displayInput: true }
   ]
  });` like this?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli sorry that was a typo i fixed it in the post

Comment: Yes, and adjust the `numberOfLine` as well, or remove that from the state and just use `this.state.lines.length`.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I did that as well the problem still persists after each input it re-render everything

Comment: change `key={this.state.numberOfLine}` to `key={l.id}`. Otherwise all your elements get the same key and that will confuse react.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli thank you that fixed the unique key thing. But my initial problem still persists. And the displayInput is messed up idk why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `id` of the line for the `key` for each `NewLine` component.

<s>Also, you need to use `{this.props.line.value}` instead of `{this.state.value}` in the `NewLine` component.</s>

See below

```
<React.Fragment>
            <p className=output>
                {this.state.displayInput && (
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="here"
                        value={this.state.value}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        onKeyDown={this.handelEnter}
                    />
                )}
                {this.props.line.value} OR {this.state.value}
            </p>
        </React.Fragment>
```

See this [codepen](https://codepen.io/macro6461/pen/QWWrPvR).

In the code pen I use a `div` instead of `React.Fragment` but that's just because the fragment was throwing an error in a codepen.

**EDIT**

It actually works with `this.state.value` so depending on use case, both  `this.props.line.value` and `this.state.value` works.

Comment: Yes but it only updates after a user clicks enter before that there is not text

Comment: It actually works when you use `this.state.value`. I'll edit the answer and update the codepen.

Comment: I will add my code on the codepen and link it as well

Comment: Sort of but i am doing the same thing in my editor and it does not work here is the https://codepen.io/shloksomani/pen/PooevZM

Comment: I just tried it and it works it just doesn't autofocus so you have to click the new line.